# Problem when displaying errors in friendly way in Zapier

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I'm trying to display errors in a friendly way, but I'm always getting the errors stack trace with console logs that **I want to get rid of.**

The idea is to create a Lead in our platform using any source, for example, Google Sheets.
When an invalid email is provided in the lead and posted to our API, I'm getting the expected message I want to display followed by the stack trace.

My custom error message is

```
INVALID FORMAT for email. Object didn't pass validation for format email: as1@mail.
```

But this is what I'm getting:

```
INVALID FORMAT for email. Object didn't pass validation for format email: as1@mail. What happened: Starting POST request to https://cosmo-charon-production.herokuapp.com/v1/lead/vehicle Received 500 code from https://cosmo-charon-production.herokuapp.com/v1/lead/vehicle?api-key=gIBp04HVdTgsHShJj6bXKwjbcxXTogsh after 62ms Received content "{"code":"SCHEMA_VALIDATION_FAILED","message":"Request validation failed: Parameter (lead) failed sch" INVALID FORMAT for email. Object didn't pass validation for format email: as1@mail. Console logs:
```

[Image showing error displayed in Zapier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqFBo.png)

---

I've added a middleware for ErrorHandling into `afterResponse`, just as one of the examples provided in Zapier docs.

The function `analyzeAndParse()` receives an error object from the API and returns a string with the error message translated in a friendly way

```js
const checkForErrors = (response, z) => {
  // If we get a bad status code, throw an error, using the ErrorTranslator
  if (response.status >= 300) {
    throw new Error(analyzeAndParse(response.json))
  }
  // If no errors just return original response
  return response
}
```

This is the code that creates a Lead in our platform, making a request to our API.

```js
function createLead (z, bundle) {
  const industry = bundle.inputData.industry

  // add product to request based on the inputFields
  leadType[industry].addProductFields(bundle.inputData)

  const requestOptions = {
    url: `${baseUrl}lead/${_.kebabCase(industry)}`,
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(checkSourceForCreate(bundle.inputData)),
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
  }

  return z.request(requestOptions).then((response) => {
    if (response.status >= 300) {
      throw new Error(analyzeAndParse(response.content))
    }
    const content = JSON.parse(response.content)
    if (content && content.leads) {
      // get only the last lead from the list of leads
      content.lead = content.leads[0]
      delete content.leads
    }
    return content
  })
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong, you are seeing raw request-response too because you are the app owner. Try to test this app in another Zapier account, in different zapier account you will see only an error

Comment: @KishorPatidar Thanks a lot ! That was the problem!